# Render List of Lists with StringTemplate

Tags: java, stringtemplate

Please help me to render the following Java structure with StringTemplate:

```
List<List<String>> listOfListsOfStrings;
```

The output should be as follows (where ListXStringY is a string contained in position X, Y):

- List1String1, List1String2, ...
- List2String1, List2String2, List2String3, ...
- ...
- ListNString1, ...

The number of strings in different second-level lists can vary. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try using nested iterators:

```
$list:{<li>$it:{$it$,}$</li>}$
```

Should print:

```
<li>List1String1,List1String2,</li><li>List2String1,List2String2,List2String3,</li>
```